# Flutter scrollbar that is in horizontal scrollview doesnt show correctly inner scrollview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-scrollbar

[image]

So, I have bigger scroll view that scrolls horizontally, and inside - little box (red color) and smaller scrollview (orange color) that scrolls vertically.
There are two scrollbars on the bigger scrollview (1 - for horizontal), and second - for vertical inner.

And the problem - vertical scrollbar doesnt look right, because it can go only like blue arrow shows, and I want it to have either full height of the bigger scrollview, or be right near scrollable vertical part, but then dont hide itself if scrolled in horizontal direction.

Run on dartPad

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ScrollSizingWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollSizingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollSizingWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollSizingWidget> createState() => _ScrollSizingWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollSizingWidgetState extends State<ScrollSizingWidget> {
  final ScrollController _horizontal = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController _vertical = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _horizontal.dispose();
    _vertical.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
        controller: _vertical,
        notificationPredicate: (notification) => notification.depth == 1,
        child: Scrollbar(
          controller: _horizontal,
          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _horizontal,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              width: 1000,
              child: Column(
                children:[
                  Container(width: 1000, height: 200, color: Colors.green),
                  Flexible(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _vertical,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 700,
                        width: 1000,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  
                ]
              )
            ),
 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yeah, sure, @YeasinSheikh here is gist on github with some containers https://gist.github.com/Ne0n11/0f961bb6a677447f9184a18cdbc2121c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used your code to reproduce the issue. If I understood your needs right, here is the fix:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ScrollSizingWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class ScrollSizingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollSizingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollSizingWidget> createState() => _ScrollSizingWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollSizingWidgetState extends State<ScrollSizingWidget> {
  late final ScrollController _horizontal;
  late final ScrollController _vertical;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _horizontal = ScrollController();
    _vertical = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _horizontal.dispose();
    _vertical.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scrollbar(
        controller: _horizontal,
        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _horizontal,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 1000,
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _vertical,
              scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _vertical,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 1000,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 1000,
                      width: 1000,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Firstly, you say that your main `SingleChildScrollView` scrolls horizontally, but your widget tree starts with a `Scrollbar` which uses a vertical `ScrollController`. So you should create your widgets step by step, as you explained.

Also, since you want to see the vertical `Scrollbar` through your main `SingleChildScrollView`, I wrapped both(red and orange Containers) with `Scrollbar` and `SingleChildScrollView` to have the effect you want. Furthermore, I connected these `Scrollbar` and `SingleChildScrollView` with the same horizontal `ScrollController`. So now, not only the orange `Container`, but both are scrollable and stick together, not independent.

If you don't want the red `Container` being scrolled along with the orange `Container`, check this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ScrollSizingWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class ScrollSizingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollSizingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollSizingWidget> createState() => _ScrollSizingWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollSizingWidgetState extends State<ScrollSizingWidget> {
  late final ScrollController _horizontal;
  late final ScrollController _vertical;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _horizontal = ScrollController();
    _vertical = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _horizontal.dispose();
    _vertical.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scrollbar(
        controller: _horizontal,
        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _horizontal,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 1000,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 1000,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    controller: _vertical,
                    scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _vertical,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 700,
                        width: 1000,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Lastly, `Scrollbar`'s position in iOS is a bit buggy because of the notch, etc. So I wrapped your `ScrollSizingWidget` with `SafeArea` to fix the issue in iOS.

If these answers are not what you expect, please don't hesitate to write.

Edit: After your explanations in the comments below, I have created another fix. I believe `CustomScrollView` and `Sliver` widgets are fits here perfectly. The red `Container`, which you want to stay in its position, should be wrapped with the `SliverAppBar`. Lastly, the orange `Container`, which you want to be able to scroll vertically, could be wrapped with `SliverFixedExtentList`. Please check the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ScrollSizingWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class ScrollSizingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollSizingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollSizingWidget> createState() => _ScrollSizingWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollSizingWidgetState extends State<ScrollSizingWidget> {
  late final ScrollController _horizontal;
  late final ScrollController _vertical;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _horizontal = ScrollController();
    _vertical = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _horizontal.dispose();
    _vertical.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scrollbar(
        controller: _horizontal,
        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _horizontal,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 1000,
            child: Scrollbar(
              controller: _vertical,
              scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
              child: CustomScrollView(
                controller: _vertical,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    toolbarHeight: 200.0,
                    collapsedHeight: 200.0,
                    pinned: true,
                    stretch: true,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    title: Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    titleSpacing: 0,
                  ),
                  SliverFixedExtentList(
                    itemExtent: 1200.0,
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (_, __) => Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      childCount: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for trying this out. But your solutions don't fit to my problem. 

So the problem is that I want vertical scrollbar to look as in your first variant ( for whole page), but so that scrollable is only red one.

Comment: @ArtiScream No problem at all :) At the end of your comment, you say: So that scrollable is the red one. Do you mean the orange one?

Comment: yea, sorry, for inconvenience. Orange, correct

Comment: I have edited my answer after your explanations and added a new solution, please check it. Hope this helps.